# why $\int \sqrt{(\sin x)^2}\, \mathrm{d}x = \int |\sin x| \,\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: integration, trigonometry

May be this is a stupid question but why $$\int \sqrt{(\sin x)^2}  \,\mathrm{d}x = \int |\sin x|  \,\mathrm{d}x$$ instead of $$\pm \int \sin x  \,\mathrm{d}x$$

I think may be because it violates the rule that a function can't have more than 1 output for a single input, which brings me to my next question does the intgrand need to be a function?

Comment: @user236182, if you are going to restrict to $x\geq 0$, then writing $\sqrt{x^2}=x$ suffices since $|x|=x~\forall~x\geq 0$. I think what you meant to write was $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|~\forall~x\in\Bbb R$.

Comment: when you use $\pm$ you do not know when things are positive and when negative. But leaving the absolute value as is, you do not face this complication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of the square root, $\sqrt{\,\cdot\,}$, in real numbers is a function that given a non-negative number $y$, we take the non-negative number $x$ such that $x^2 = y$. That's why we write $$x^2 = k \Rightarrow x = \pm\sqrt{k}$$ instead of $$x^2 = k \Rightarrow x = \sqrt{k}.$$

We have to put the $\pm$ sign because the square root itself only considers the positive answer.

**Observation:** If the answer of square root was the two numbers, then it couldn't be a function.

Answer (score 4):

In general: The symbol $\sqrt{a}$, for $a>0$ means the [**positive** square root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root#Properties_and_uses) of the number $a$, so $\sqrt{a^2}$ is the positive number $x$ such that $x^2=a^2$, so it is $|a|$.

Answer (score 1):

Notice, in general $\sqrt {a^2}=|a|=a\ \ \ \forall\ \  a\ge 0$
$$\int \sqrt{(\sin^2x)}\ dx=\int |\sin x|\ dx=\int \sin x\ dx\ \ \ \forall \ \ x\in \left[2n\pi, 2n\pi+\pi\right]$$
$$=-\cos x+C$$

> **Edit:** $$|\sin x|=\begin{cases}-\sin x\ \ \ \ \forall \ \ \ x\in[(2n-1)\pi, 2n\pi]\\
> \sin x\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \forall \ \ \ x\in[2n\pi, (2n+1)\pi]
>  \end{cases}$$
>   where, $n$ is any integer